# Node Pollyfill for StencilJS

Tags: node.js, rollupjs, stenciljs

I have a third party lib as a dependency in my StencilJS application. This lib uses oob modules that come with node: stream, events, ..etc. Its my understanding after reading the [docs,](http://rollup-plugin-node-polyfills) that using `rollup-plugin-node-polyfills` within my `stencil.config.ts` would allow me to use those modules which are typically only usable in a nodeJS app.

```
import { Config } from '@stencil/core';
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills';

export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'mycomponents',
  plugins: [
    nodePolyfills(),
  ]
};
```

After following the config in the docs mentioned I'm still getting an error

[image]

Comment: Yup from what I can tell this is supposed to work... maybe you should raise a bug report in https://github.com/ionic-team/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like updating node to the latest stable version fixed it. Went from 10 --> 13